# jdeveloper class diagram to image

Tags: uml, jdeveloper, xmi

I have jdeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.1.2.0.0

I have created a pretty complex UML class diagram, and the only way (that I know of) is to export it which creates an xmi file. Is there some sort of way to create an image of it? I can't do much with the XMI file other than import it back to jdeveloper..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the diagram and choose Publish...